# Report showing the days with the most orders per day

Tags: orders, sql, sales

I'd like to get a list of orders per days. Sorted from most to least so that I can easily see on which days the most orders where placed.

A text report (SQL statement) is enough, I do not need a fancy report in the backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement can be used to retrieve a list of orders per day:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as orders_per_day, date(created_at) as day
FROM sales_flat_order
GROUP BY date(created_at)
ORDER BY orders_per_day DESC
```

Comment: like same how to get overall order sales per day @Anna Völkl